# Google Calendar API PHP Notification Expiration Value

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am successfully registering for Google Calendar API Change Notifications using PHP:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($service);
$channel->setId(<some random ID>);
$channel->setType('web_hook');
$channel->setAddress('https://www.myserver.net/triggerCode.php');
$timetoExpire = time()+3600000;
$channel->setExpiration($timetoExpire);
$watchEvent = $service->events->watch('<some_calendar_name>', $channel);
```

EXCEPT this only works if the $channel->setExpiration line is commented out.

I get an error the ttl is invalid.  I have tried setting the expiration to a number of seconds (e.g.  6000), a number of milliseconds (e.g. 600000), and time() plus some milliseconds and I always get the same error:

```
Invalid ttl value for channel -1402834554'
```

How am I supposed to set this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working.  This PHP code works:

```
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($service);
 $channel->setId($uniqueID);
 $channel->setType('web_hook');
 $channel->setAddress('https://mydomain.net/notificationCallBack.php');

 $timetoExpire = time()+3600000;
 $optParams = array('ttl' => $timetoExpire);
 $channel->setParams($optParams);

 $watchEvent = $service->events->watch($calendarID, $channel);
```

The above expiration is 42 days hence but the expiration winds up set to 30 days hence.  I am guessing that that is the upper limit.

Answer (score 2):

From [the API documentatio](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch?hl=es)n it looks like `watch` event doesn't include the `expiration` parameter.

The request takes:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "token": string,
  "type": string,
  "address": string,
  "params": {
    "ttl": string
  }
}
```

The *response* contains `expiration`, but not the request itself:

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": string,
  "resourceId": string,
  "resourceUri": string,
  "token": string,
  "expiration": long
}
```

Maybe you mean `ttl`, which is part of the request `params`?

---

FYI: It also looks like `expiration` is defined as `Date and time of notification channel expiration, expressed as a Unix timestamp, in milliseconds.`

Comment: In the PHP code at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php there is reference to Google_Calendar_Service_Channel->setExpiration($expiration).

Comment: And there's also a `setPayload` function that shows up nowhere in the API documentation.  That PHP API implementation is [still in beta](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads).  I trust official API documentation over a beta implementation.

Comment: As Llama points out, the expiration is only supposed to be set on responses, not requests. Try setting params.ttl in seconds instead.