# Google push notifications channel is expired

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I need implement Google push notification logic to repair channels.
I know that Google provides header field `X-Goog-Channel-Expiration`. One of ways to repair channel is to add crone expression to monitor expiration `date-time` and call handler by event. I'm interesting in another way solution...

Can I receive message about Google push notifications channel expiration?
Which field(value) lets me know that channel is expired?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests):

> Currently there is no automatic way to renew a notification channel. When a channel is close to its expiration, you must create a new one by calling the **`watch`** method. As always, you must use a unique value for the **`id`** property of the new channel. Note that there is likely to be an "overlap" period of time when the two notification channels for the same resource are active.

**`X-Goog-Channel-Expiration`** can be found in the header part of the notification message (sometimes present).

```
POST https://sampleurl.com/notifications // Your receiving URL.
Content-Type: application/json; utf-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 398348u3tu83ut8uu38
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events
X-Goog-Resource-State:  exists
X-Goog-Message-Number: 10
```

I've found a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592375/5995040) that you can set the expiration upon requesting a watch method. Here is the code:

```
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($service);
 $channel->setId($uniqueID);
 $channel->setType('web_hook');
 $channel->setAddress('https://sample.net/notificationCallBack.php');

 $timetoExpire = time()+3600000;
 $optParams = array('ttl' => $timetoExpire);
 $channel->setParams($optParams);

 $watchEvent = $service->events->watch($calendarID, $channel);
```

Now that you've set the expiration date, you now check the header part and see **`X-Goog-Channel-Expiration`**.

> The channel's expiration time, if it has one, is included as a Unix timestamp (in ms) in the information returned by the watch method.

Hope this helps.